# cakephp Update field

Tags: php, cakephp

How do i force cake to update a field and not insert a new record.

It should fail if the id does not exist in the db

I found to force a insertion i can do [`'updated' => false`](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1031/Saving-Your-Data) so if i do `'updated' => true` will it work

Answer (score 17):

If you want to just update a field, use the `saveField` method of the model

```
$this->Order->id    = $id;
$this->Order->saveField('status', 'VOID');
```

Reference : http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html

Comment: That's just a static property in the class. Same as using 'Void' in there

Answer (score 4):

```
//Create: id isn't set or is null
$this->Recipe->create();
$this->Recipe->save($this->data);

//Update: id is set to a numerical value 


$this->Recipe->id = 2;
$this->Recipe->save($this->data);
```

see http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html

Comment: so if the id doe not exist in db it will be rejected and will not insert a new record

Comment: I believe that is the case, but i'm not 100% positive, easy to find out ;)

Answer (score 0):

### Use Model::exists

To ensure that the record does exist, use [Model::Exists](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/additional-methods-and-properties.html#model-exists-id). For example:

```
function updateFoo($id, $value) {
    if (!$this->exists($id) {
        return false;
    }

    $this->id = $id;
    return $this->saveField('foo', $value);
}
```

This would act like so:

```
$false = $model->updateFoo(false, $value);
$false = $model->updateFoo(0, $value);
$false = $model->updateFoo('doesnotexist', $value);
$true = $model->updateFoo('doesexist', $value);
```